Failed to connect to an aws ec2 instance: An error occurred (IncorrectInstanceState) when calling the StartInstances operation
I am trying to connect to an aws ec2 instane especially g4dn.xlarge with aws ec2 start command
 aws ec2 start-instances --instance-ids i-************

with the specific id of the instance
But I encounter this error
An error occurred (IncorrectInstanceState) when calling the StartInstances operation: The instance 'i-********' is not in a state from which it can be started.


What is the state of the instance?

It was stopped.

After you make sure your access key is configured properly,first thing you need to check is instance satate before applying any other operations.
you can use the following command to identify the state of your instance:
aws ec2 describe-instance-status --instance-ids i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx --query 'InstanceStatuses[*].{InstanceId:InstanceId,InstanceState:InstanceState.Name,SystemStatus:SystemStatus.Status,InstanceStatus:InstanceStatus.Status}'

you need to figure out what state your instance is in any other state apart from stopped, you cannot start the instace.
note: most likely the issue is when you enter the access key and secret key while doing "aws configure" you insert spaces, please make sure to check that.
